# transfer data between 2 lua_State's

Tags: c, lua

I have С function in first lua_State. How to copy this function to second lua_State? I tried to use lua_xmove but it does not work for me
(PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API attempt to index a function value)

```
void lua_setfield (lua_State *L, int index, const char *k)
{
    if (lua_isfunction(L, lua_gettop(L)) && !strcmp(k, "myfunction"))
    {
            lua_pushvalue(L, lua_gettop(L));
            lua_xmove(L, myluastate, 1);
            o_lua_setfield(myluastate, index, k);
    }
    o_lua_setfield(L,index,k);
}
```

o_lua_setfield - original lua_setfield function
lua_setfield - hooked setfield function
myfunction - function that i need

Comment: `lua_xmove` exchanges values between different threads **of the same Lua VM**.  Make sure your second state `myluastate` was created by invoking `lua_newthread`, not `luaL_newstate`